# How to compute the range in Makefile

Tags: linux, makefile, gnu

Here is my Makefile and the output, how to print the range like `[1-5, 7, 9-10]` ?

```
$ ls /tmp/foo
foo10.txt  foo1.txt  foo2.txt  foo3.txt  foo4.txt  foo5.txt  foo7.txt  foo9.txt

$ cat Makefile 
DIR1 := /tmp/foo/
COMMA :=,
EMPTY :=
SPACE := $(EMPTY) $(EMPTY)
VERSIONS := $(subst $(SPACE),$(COMMA),$(patsubst foo%,%,$(basename $(notdir $(wildcard $(DIR1)/foo*.txt)))))
all:
        $(info versions is [${VERSIONS}])

$ make
versions is [10,1,2,3,4,5,7,9]
```

Comment: I can call shell commands, if that's going to help.

Comment: Are you only looking for a Makefile solution or will accept a bash script as well?

Comment: Bash is fine too, I can call a shell commands from my Makefile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is pipeline of shell commands to get your job done:

```
printf '%s\n' foo*[0-9].txt |
sed 's/[^0-9]*//g' |
sort -n |
awk 'function prnt(sep){printf "%s%s", s, (p > s ? "-" p : "") sep}
NR==1{s = $1} p < $1-1{prnt(","); s = $1} {p = $1} END{prnt(ORS)}'

1-5,7,9-10
```

Commands are:

1. `printf` to print each filename on separate lines
2. `sed` to remove everything except digits
3. `sort` to sort numerically to get the range in right sequence
4. `awk` to set the range and format the results

Answer (score 4):

There are several approaches:

1. If you know the maximum possible value: First, add `SHELL=bash` so that brace espansion works. Then use something like `$(shell {1..10})`, and pass that result through `$(wildcard)` to exclude non-existent files.
2. Pipe lines through `sort -n`, again in `$(shell)`.
3. Pad numbers on the left with `0`s, then sort normally.